# Странное преобразование к (void)

Tags: c

```c
void vApplicationStackOverflowHook(xTaskHandle *pxTask,signed portCHAR *pcTaskName)
{
    (void)pxTask;
    (void)pcTaskName;
    for(;;);
}
```

Что в данном случае делает преобразование к `(void)`?